# jQuery mobile not loading new page scripts

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-mobile, django-templates, transition

Using jQuery Mobile with Django: During the page transitions, the base scripts seems to be loading fine, but going from one page to the next, new page's scripts under the header do not load up in the browser.

To be more specific:

1. I load my home page by typing in the url, and everything works.
2. I load the next page by clicking on a link within home page, and the
   DOM loads, but scripts associated with the page in the page header,
   do not load.
3. If I refresh this page, or I type the URL of this page
   in the browser directly (bypassing the page transitions), the page
   loads the scripts the way it should.

I know that jquery mobile tries to implement page transitions using ajax, but I am hoping I can keep the scripts in header/footer. I would hate to have to put the scripts under `<div data-role="page" >`

Comment: I ended up overwriting the ajax loading functionality, and used  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;

Answer (score 10):

That is because jQuery Mobile loads only the code within the first `data-role="page"` element in the DOM.

There are a couple of options you can choose from on how to fix this:

1. You can put your page-specific JS inside the `data-role="page"` element, so it will be loaded when jQuery Mobile loads the page via AJAX.
2. You can put all of your code in a single JS file and include it in every page on the site, it will only be loaded on full-page refreshes but this way all the code for your site will be available all the time (after minification and compression you really have to have a lot of code to make this inefficient).

I'm sure there are other methods as well but here are a couple I've had work for me.

Comment: exactly what I was afraid of. Thanks

Comment: I just tested this and it still removed the script tag from INSIDE my one and only `<div data-role="page">` tag. There must be another reason why script tags are removed or not rendered.

Comment: I should also note that the javascript does get run, it just doesn't show up.

Answer (score 5):

If you just have one or two pages that require the JS to load this is what I did. Any links on your site that link to that page should be forced to 'load' the new page.

Add this to the link

```
rel="external"
```

Comment: this is what i resorted to, but by adding a tag to the form element to make it behav ethes ame way - by not using ajax

Answer (score 3):

I tried adding this to the link and it worked for me

```
target="_parent"
```

When I added this to my link (I still have the rel="external" though) it helped and the other page loaded with all of the scripts intact :)