# Django and loading jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, django, pageload

It is possible to have scripts tags in child pages and to be rendered by `Django` whey they (child pages are loaded / showed)?

I have a mobile web app which has this structure

```
ROOT
--PAGE1 (here I'd like to have the script rendered by Django)
--PAGE2
--PAGE3
--PAGE4
```

The reason is because on the second page I have custom controls like: flip switch, buttons, etc. that will do something specific on that page.

Code snippets:

```
//This one gets rendered only when root page is loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        //But the control / html element its on the second page
        $("#myswitch").change(function() {
                console.log("Switch changed!");
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. What you will need is a base template and a custom block for your end body scripts, here is an example:

base.html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
  {% block tail_scripts %}{% endblock tail_scripts %}
</body>
</html>
```

page1..4.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block tail_scripts %}
<script src="/path/to/custom/script/if/needed.js"></script>
<script type="src/javascript">
  (function() {
    console.log('Build something awesome!');
  })();
</script>
{% endblock tail_scripts %}
```

Comment: Thanks for code snippets and pointing me to the right direction! I still have a question. Why the script doesn't get loaded only after I refresh the page and then the whole design breaks (css with jQuery because the path is invalid after refresh). No idea how to solve this...

Comment: What do you mean by the script doesn't get loaded? Is django producing a 404 on the resource or is the browser not executing it?

Comment: I've figure it out in the end with the path but now I've created a block in header and on my extended page I want to load another JavaScript file but it gets in the DOM only after I refresh the page. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Fixed by putting the block inside page div as [this answer says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418309/jquery-mobile-not-loading-new-page-scripts)