# JQuery Mobile: <script> tags do not show up but code runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'll refer to this ticket as step in the right direction for what I need:

[jQuery mobile not loading new page scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418309/jquery-mobile-not-loading-new-page-scripts)

One of the answers states that any code NOT nested in the first `$([data-role=page])` tag in jQuery  mobile will NOT show up in the html. I don't know if maybe this is a browser quirk or not but regardless, the code IS getting run despite it NEVER showing up. I find this difficult if I want to debug the js code since I can't add break points to any of it.

I've also had a problem with using the Jquery autocomplete plugin as it only works ONE time and then after submitting the form and returning the the form it no longer works. I believe this is because the page (well a partial piece of it by jquery mobile) gets reloaded and the autocomplete plugin is no longer bound to my textbox. I've tried using the `live` and `on` methods to make sure they get rebound but this doesn't work.

Can any javascript/jquery mobile geniuses out there help me out with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: 1) are you using single page or multi-page model 2) is Ajax enabled 3) are you loading JS in head for all pages 4) when/at which point are you facing problem? 5) add some code pls :)